# PHP server redirect

Tags: php, server-side

I have been trying to use server side redirect for the drop down menu on my main page. I need the selected option to be remembered using cookies so that it will redirect to the last visited option itself.

This is what I have done so far, but couldn't able to figure it out where I m doing mistake.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){
$newcity=$_POST['city'];
#set cookies
setcookie("city",$newcity,time()+22896000);

}

if ((!isset($_COOKIE['city']) )){
$city = "";
}


else{
header("location:http://example.com/".$_COOKIE['city'].""); 
}
?>

<form action= "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method ="POST">
<select name="city">
<option value ="toronto">Toronto</option>
<option value ="ottawa">Ottawa</option>
<option value ="kingston">Kingston</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Does it work if you add an input `<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value=1>` to the HTML? I'm pretty sure inputs of type `submit` don't get sent with the POST request.

Comment: I wouldn't add a hidden input, just check to see if `$_POST['city']` is set instead of the submit button.  Also you can read the posted values of submit inputs.

Comment: Sidenote: You can remove 2 parentheses `if (!isset($_COOKIE['city']) ){`

Comment: @JCOC611 still its not working. I have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){
  $newcity = $_POST['city'];
  setcookie("cookie_city", $newcity, time()+22896000);
}

if ((!isset($_COOKIE['cookie_city']))){
  $city = "";
} else{
   header("Location: http://example.com/".$_COOKIE['cookie_city']);
   exit(0); // <<< Try this
}
?>

<form action= "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method ="POST">
<select name="city">
<option value ="toronto">Toronto</option>
<option value ="ottawa">Ottawa</option>
<option value ="kingston">Kingston</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Two thoughts:

1. Try use `exit(0)` after the redirect.
2. Use a cookie name different from your POST and GET variables. Maybe your server is configured in some way that overrides POST, GET and cookies.

Comment: I have tried using this as well. Its not redirecting. When I trigger submit button, it attaches /index.php at the end of my domain name in the location bar (like example.com/index.php)

Comment: The problem remains the same. If I select "toronto" and click submit, it includes /index.php instead of value. When i click the submit button again, it then redirects to /toronto.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is present because you can't access a cookie value on the same page that you set it. Hence why it only works when you reload the page.

You'd be best to redirect them right after the cookie setting:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    $newcity = $_POST['city'];
    setcookie("cookie_city", $newcity, time()+22896000);
    die(header("Location: http://example.com/".$new_city));
}

if ((!isset($_COOKIE['cookie_city']))){
    $city = "";
} else{
    header("Location: http://example.com/".$_COOKIE['cookie_city']);
    exit(0); // <<< Try this
}
```

That way, you'll have the cookie set and then user is redirected either way.

Do you still need that end block though? Are they always going to redirect to the city they selected?

Comment: its still not working. Check [link](http://solutionjug.com) . It is now redirecting but to example.com only, not including the subdirectory.

Comment: Nope its still the same. Is there any alternative way of doing this? except Javascript as I already did this but its displaying the main page while redirecting to the subdirectory.

Comment: You could use sessions.